# PHP code saying input is empty but it's not?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, rows

I'm having a problem with my php code, it seems that it returns "Password Should Not Be empty" when I do input a password. I think it might be coming from my html code because I make them input it twice. Do I need to make another variable in my database for confirm password?

```
<?php
$firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname');
$lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
if (!empty($firstname)) {
    if (!empty($lastname)) {
        if (!empty($email)) {
            if (!empty($password)) {
                $host = "127.0.0.1:3307";
                $dbusername = "root";
                $dbpassword = "";
                $dbname = "register";
                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbfirstname, $dblastname, $dbemail,
                    $dbpassword);
                if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                        . mysqli_connect_error());
                } else {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (firstname, lastname, email, password) values ('$firstname','$lastname','email','password')";
                    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                        echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Password should not be empty";
                die();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Username should not be empty";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);exit;` at the very top to see what data you're getting. Is the password there?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to [edit] your post and indent the code properly. It will make it a lot easier to help debug your problem.

Comment: Show your html maybe you've put wrong name for input

Comment: for `echo "Password should not be empty";` in code = this `if (!empty($lastname))`

Comment: If you are asking the password twice maybe you have two inputs with the same name, and maybe that's the problem. Please show us the html code

Comment: You need to post your form HTML, filter_input is either returning false or null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because your post value is `$_POST['psw']`, while your code is expecting `$_POST['password']`. Either change your HTML form, or your PHP code so that the values are the same.

Your code is *very* confusing. I made it a little simpler, try this and see if you still get the same error:

```
# Check to see if you're getting the right variables in the first place:
var_dump($_POST); //Remove once you're sure you're getting the right stuff

if(!$firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname')){
    die("First name should not be empty");
}
if(!$lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname')){
    die("Last name should not be empty");
}
if(!$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email')){
    die("Email should not be empty");
}
if(!$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password')){
    die("Password should not be empty");
}

$host = "127.0.0.1:3307";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "register";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbfirstname, $dblastname, $dbemail, $dbpassword);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (firstname, lastname, email, password) values ('$firstname','$lastname','email','password')";
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "\r\n" . $conn->error;
    $conn->close();
    exit;
}

echo "New record is inserted successfully";
```

**General guidelines**

1. Don't nest `if()` statements. It makes following code very confusing.
2. If a boolean outcome is a deal breaker, have that outcome first in the if/else statement. For instance if the SQL query fails, have the negative outcome first in the `if()` statement (which will stop your code), and skip the else statement all together.
3. Comment your code.

Comment: array(6) { ["firstname"]=> string(5) "Bardo" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "Perez" ["email"]=> string(20) "Bardoperez@yahoo.com" ["psw"]=> string(3) "123" ["psw-repeat"]=> string(3) "123" ["remember"]=> string(2) "on" } Password should not be empty    // is the output with this code, it looks like everything is going through but it's still not working or transferring the data to my DB

Comment: Thank you for alerting me about this, I fixed it and the problem was fixed, but I'm now getting undefined errors, hence below... PS thank you for your help, me and my partner appreciate it much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="overstack.php"> 
  <div class="container">
    <br> 
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="firstname"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" required>

    <label for="lastname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastname" required>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

this is my html form for the php code above

Comment: I updated my answer to include why the results are not as expected. (Value name mismatch.)